# How to set font, line spacing and header/footer margins?

Tags: fonts, margins, line-spacing

I need to write some text for my university and I figured I should use `LaTeX` to get familiar with the system. I've read some basic tutorials etc, but they didn't help me with the following:

There are some rather strict requirements on how the text must be formatted and on the page layout:
* Text must have font size 12pt and font 'Arial'
* Spacing between lines must be 1.5x
* Left margin must be 3cm, right margin must be 2cm
* The header must have 1.25 cm distance from the top
* The footer must have 1.25 cm distance from the bottom

This is what I got right now:

```
% Set font size
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

% Set paper size and margins. Seems to work correctly.
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

% Needed for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

% For testing, visualizes margins.
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

% Set line spacing to 1.5
\begin{onehalfspace}

Content.\\
Next line.

\end{onehalfspace}

\end{document}
```

So, here are my questions:
1. I haven't found any way to set the font to 'Arial'. I would guess that it is a simple command. How is it done?
2. Is there a better way to set the line spacing than what I have done?
3. How do I change the distance between header and top, or footer and bottom?

I hope those are not too many questions for one topic. Sorry if some of those seem obvious, I really tried solving them myself. Maybe I just don't know the right sites for things like that yet.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: This requirements are Windows(MS-Word) based and should be taken with care. `12pt` for Word isn't `12pt` in LaTeX. Basically, unless `xelatex` (or lualatex) is used, there is no Arial font for TeX, but the font by the `helvet` package resembles Arial (somewhat)

Comment: The top/bottom margins should take `headheight` into account

Comment: Oh, I did not know that the sizes are not the same...
I think I am using pdflatex right now (I do not really understand things here, so maybe that falls into a whole other category). 
And I am on Win10, got TexMaker + MiKTeX 2.9 installed.